# Transforming text data in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Given an array of text data,

```
X = np.array(['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'cat', 'cow', 'dog'])
```

I would like to use an sklearn pipeline to produce output like

```
np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
```

My initial attempt

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('encoder', LabelEncoder()),
    ('hot', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))])
print(pipe.fit_transform(X))
```

raises `TypeError: fit_transform() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`
, as per [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3956).  I have tried editing the signature on LabelEncoder, so that `SaneLabelEncoder().fit_transform(X)` gives `[0 2 1 0 1 2]`, but then

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('encoder', SaneLabelEncoder()),
    ('hot', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))])
print(pipe.fit_transform(X))
```

gives `[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]`.  Any suggestions on getting to the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LabelBinarizer`:

```
import numpy as np                                  
from sklearn import preprocessing                                                                                                                            
X = np.array(['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'cat', 'cow', 'dog'])                                                                                                                      
binar = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()                                                                                                                                        
X_bin = binar.fit_transform(X)                                                                                                                                                
print X_bin
```

the output is:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

Comment: That's perfect -- you might add that it works in a pipeline, as a single step.  Specifically, if `pipe = Pipeline(('encoder', LabelBinarizer()),])`, then `print(pipe.fit_transform(X))` works as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

pandas has a method [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas.get_dummies) for this:

```
pd.get_dummies(X)
```

Will produce DataFrame:

```
   cat  cow  dog
0    1    0    0
1    0    0    1
2    0    1    0
3    1    0    0
4    0    1    0
5    0    0    1
```

Or if you must have an array of ints:

```
pd.get_dummies(X).values.astype(int)
```

Will yield:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```